# Postgres ENUM into Google BigQuery via Datastream

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

GCP now offers a lovely feature to replicate postgres tables directly into Bigquery.

I have managed to get this functionality setup pretty simply following the docs, however all of the columns of `ENUM` data type are not being converted and pushed into Bigquery.

Is there a solution for this?

https://cloud.google.com/datastream-for-bigquery

Comment: It would indeed be awesome to have visibility on this !